# Regular Expression to provided max 2 spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to write a regular expression in JavaScript which will satisfy the below

```
a) accept only alphabetic characters(small/caps)
b) should not exceed beyond 20 characters 
c) max 2 spaces can be provided.
```

### Valid test cases

```
a) Name
b) name
c) namea nameb
d) namea nameb namecd
e) namea  nameb (2 consecutive spaces is also valid but total number of spaces cannot be more than 2)
```

My attempt (but not working)

```
function test(){

    var originalString="abc rt t tt";
    var myRegEx = /^([a-zA-Z ]{1,20})+$/;   
    var isValid = myRegEx.test(originalString);
    alert(isValid);
}
```

What is the mistake and how to fix?

Comment: What about two consecutive spaces?

Comment: yes...it can also be valid because a  b is also valid... just missed that point (:

Comment: What is _should not exceed beyond 20 characters_, total string length or each word length?

Comment: Just two consecutive spaces are allowed?

Comment: @Tushar, total string length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex [`/^([a-zA-Z ]{1,20})+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/qI2vU5/4) will match one to twenty alphabet and/or space one or more times. So, basically this allows alphabets and spaces in any sequence any number of times.

---

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]*){0,2}$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qI2vU5/3)

```js
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]*){0,2}$/;

var result = document.getElementById('result');
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var value = this.value;

  var isValid = value.length <= 20 && regex.test(value);
  result.innerHTML = isValid ? 'Valid' : 'InValid';
  result.className = isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
}, false);
```

```css
input:valid, .valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid, .invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]*){0,2}" maxlength="20" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Explanation:**

1. `[a-zA-Z]+` Match alphabets one or more times
2. `\s`: Matches a space character
3. `{0,2}`: Match previous class zero to two times.

---

To check if the string does not exceed 20 characters, [`String.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property can be used.

```
if (str.length <= 20 && regex.test(str)) {
    // Valid
} else {
    // Invalid
}
```

Comment: Where is the 20 character limit? But you could probably use it as a first or second stage.

Comment: thanks for the update. :D Okay I thought he even meant overall limit of 20 characters. Do you know if this could also somehow included into the single regex?

Comment: @MatthiasW. That will be tricky for a regex, but JS `.length` can be used.

Comment: @Tushar, total string length should not exceed beyond 20

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar Then you can use `str.length <= 20` as shown at the bottom of answer

Comment: @Tushar, i am using <input type="text" id="txtInput" maxlength="20"/>

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar but please remember that you might want to check on the server side again for the correct format of your inputs. ;)

Comment: What is the point of using the non-captured group with `(?:`? Also, if you are going to check the length separately, you don't need the `{1,20}` etc., and can replace them with `*`.

Comment: Although there's nothing particularly wrong with doing part of the checking (for the length in this case) via JS, and actually that's often a better solution than a convoluted regexp, in this case the answer does not technically provide a solution to the stated problem which is *write a regular expression in JavaScript which will satisfy the below*.

Comment: @torazaburo you're right about both the points. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @Tushar *That will be tricky for a regex* Actually not--it's a simple look-ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the input contains only letters, with a maximum of two internal spaces, as follows:

```
/^[a-z]+ ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]+$/i
```

In other words, starting at the beginning, match  a sequence of one of more letters, then maybe a space, then a possibly empty bunch of letters, then maybe a space again, then finally a sequence of one or more letters taking you to the end.

To check the length, without having to check it using JS, add a look-ahead:

```
/^(?=.{1,20}$)[a-z]+ ?[a-z]* ?[a-z]+$/i
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^   LOOK-AHEAD TO LIMIT CHARS TO 20
```

This says, "look ahead and find between one and twenty characters up to the end of the string".